# sed query -- begin and end keyword

Tags: sed

How does the begin and end keywords in sed actually works ? Do we have to specifically mention these keywords in the data file ?

For example, if I'm trying to delete empty lines using sed using the below code:

```
sed -n '/begin/,/end/ {
       s/^$/ d
        p
        }
    '
```

Now, should the data file should have begin and end keywork in it ? I'm sorry I've tried using these two keywords without actually entering them in the data and it doesn't give me the expected o/p.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all empty lines from your file, you use:

```
sed '/^$/d` file
```

or (remove also lines only contains tabs or spaces):

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' file
```

if you want to remove empty lines only between `BBB` line and `AAA` line:

```
sed '/BBB/,/AAA/{/^$/d}` file
```

and yes, `BBB` and `AAA` must be in your file.